# How to split a private CIDR range across three AZs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, terraform

Given a 10.163.64.0/22 of 1024 addresses, how do I split my CIDR to accommodate say three teams across three AZs, allocating 128 addresses /25 each?

I think I can do it with https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/cidrsubnets but I don't understand how to produce the desired results.

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains all about it, including a section on subnetting for the required number of hosts.

Comment: @RonMaupin I do not think the question is related to subnetting as such, but more to how to use the Terraform built-in function.

Comment: @MarkoE, it is important to know how that works before writing something. It is a huge mistake to do network programming without a thorough understand of how it works, and we end up with the extremely vulnerable applications, the programmer blindly accepting the result without knowing exactly what the result should be and how the result was derived.

Comment: I agree with that, but I didn't get such an impression from the question. Of course, I might be wrong. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the example from the link you posted to get to where you want. If we look at that:

```
> cidrsubnets("10.1.0.0/16", 4, 4, 8, 4)
[
  "10.1.0.0/20",
  "10.1.16.0/20",
  "10.1.32.0/24",
  "10.1.48.0/20",
]
```

The first part is the CIDR of course and the second is listed in the docs as `...`:

> cidrsubnets(prefix, newbits...)

This means subnetting will be done for as many `newbits` you add (from [1]):

> The remaining arguments, indicated as newbits above, each specify the number of additional network prefix bits for one returned address range. The return value is therefore a list with one element per newbits argument, each a string containing an address range in CIDR notation.

The `newbits` in this context is the number of borrowed bits from the original CIDR. So if we take the CIDR of `10.1.0.0/16` the sequence `4, 4, 8, 4` means that there will be 4, 4, 8 and 4 bits borrowed which will create the subnets:

```
  "10.1.0.0/20", # 4 bits borrowed, was /16 now is /20
  "10.1.16.0/20", # 4 bits borrowed, was /16 now is /20
  "10.1.32.0/24", # 8 bits borrowed, was /16 now is /24
  "10.1.48.0/20", # 4 bits borrowed, was /16 now is /20
```

In your case, that would then be:

```
cidrsubnets("10.163.64.0/22", 3, 3, 3)
```

By using `terraform console`, this will create the following subnets:

```
> cidrsubnets("10.163.64.0/22", 3, 3, 3)
tolist([
  "10.163.64.0/25",
  "10.163.64.128/25",
  "10.163.65.0/25",
])
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/cidrsubnets