# Splitting a cidr range in Terraform into two services?

Tags: terraform, cidr

Continuing from [How to split a private CIDR range across three AZs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72853571/how-to-split-a-private-cidr-range-across-three-azs)

Say I have 1024 address CIDR range 10.162.192.0/22 that I need to split into 32 addresses (5 bits) across two services.

I know I can run in `terraform console`:

```
cidrsubnets("10.162.192.0/22", 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)

tolist([
  "10.162.192.0/27",
  "10.162.192.32/27",
  "10.162.192.64/27",
  "10.162.192.96/27",
  "10.162.192.128/27",
  "10.162.192.160/27",
])
```

But what I don't understand is how to split the command. For example I want:

```
internal = cidrsubnets("10.162.192.0/22", 5, 5, 5) # correct
public = cidrsubnets("10.162.192.64/27", 5, 5, 5) # wrong output
```

The public variable are totally wrong with 1 address:

```
> cidrsubnets("10.162.192.64/27", 5, 5, 5)
tolist([
  "10.162.192.64/32",
  "10.162.192.65/32",
  "10.162.192.66/32",
])
```

I want to continue from "10.162.192.64/27":

```
([
  "10.162.192.96/27",
  "10.162.192.128/27",
  "10.162.192.160/27",
])
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: " totally wrong with 1 address" - that's not wrong. That's exactly what you specified it to create: `27 + 5 = 32`.

Answer (score 2):

The output of `cidrsubnets("10.162.192.64/27", 5, 5, 5)` is perfectly fine. `27 + 5 = 32` resulting in individual IP addresses. If you want to generate 32 CIDRs, you run the `cidrsubnets` command once, and then split the result:

```
locals {
  all_cidrs = cidrsubnets("10.162.192.64/27", [for i in range(6): 5]...)

  internal = [for idx, cidr in local.all_cidrs: cidr if idx < 3]
  public = [for idx, cidr in local.all_cidrs: cidr if idx >= 3]
}
```

Comment: Hi @marcin, that doesn't give me what I want?

Comment: @hendry What do you mean? This will create 32 subnets, as you asked.

Comment: I want 3 more subnets of 32 addresses, continuing from 10.162.192.64/27

Comment: @hendry You can just change `range(32)` to `range(6)`, and you will get 3 internal and 3 private subnets of 32 addresses. Exactly as you want.

Comment: I don't want to necessarily generate the ranges in advance, I want to know what is next after 10.162.58.0/26 after 6 newbits. The answer is 10.162.58.64/26 but I am not sure how to get that from Terraform cidrsubnet commands.

Comment: @hendry You can't do that. You are misunderstanding how CIDRs work in tf.

Comment: @hendry How did it go? Still unclear how you can get the cidrs?